# Trouble binding ComboBox to ObservableCollection<>

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox

I'm having some trouble binding an ObserveableCollection to a combo box.
To give some perspective I have a class like so:

```
class LogOnUser
{
    #region Members
    string _UserName;
    string _Password;
    #endregion

    #region Construction
    public LogOnUser(string username)
    {
        _UserName = username;
    }

    public LogOnUser(string username, string password)
    {
        _UserName = username;
        _Password = password;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public string Username
    {
        get { return _UserName; }
        set { _UserName = value; }
    }

    public string Password
    {
        get { return _Password; }
        set { _Password = value; }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

And then I have another class that uses LogOnUser in an ObserveableCollection:

```
class LogOnUserCollection: ObservableCollection<LogOnUser>
{
    public LogOnUserCollection() : base()
    {
        Add(new LogOnUser("User1", "password"));
        Add(new LogOnUser("User2", "password"));
    }
}
```

I have an instance of LogOnUserCollection in a ViewModel that I've named `LogOnUsers`, and I'm binding this to the `ItemsSource` of a combo box in my View. However I just want to display the `Username` property of my collection, so it would have "User1" and "User2" as it's items, but what is actually happening is my ComboBox is just displaying "LogOnUsers.LogOnUser" as its two items. 
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**Update** Binding xaml code

```
<UserControl x:Class="MVVM.View"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVM"
         mc:Ignorable="d">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:PasswordEntryViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:LogOnUserCollection x:Key="LogOnUserCollection"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding LogOnUserCollection}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Did you set the DisplayMember on the ComboBox?

Comment: could you please include the binding code

Comment: yea no guesses without xaml

Comment: Appologies, I've now added the xaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a few more properties than just ItemsSource

A typical combobox usually looks like --

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ITEMS}"
              DisplayMemberPath="PROPERTY_NAME"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SELECTED_ITEM}"/>
```

Display member would tell which property should be used to display text in combobox.

And selected item as name suggests will give you the selected item so that you can use it. (though selected item is not directly related to your question but in most cases you will be using it)

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! Am I right in thinking that SELECTED_ITEM would just be a string in my ViewModel?

Comment: selected item is the type of object that is bound to your combobox, so in your case its of type LogOnUser

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the display member path as shown below;

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding LogOnUserCollection}"
      DisplayMemberPath="Username"/>
```